# Implementing a Certificate Chain Validator using Pythin

Tags: python-3.x, pyopenssl

I am trying to implement a Certificate chain validator using python's Openssl. I create a list of certificates and try to loop over them using:

```
for chain in chains:
    # print(type(chain))
    store_ctx = crypto.X509StoreContext(store, chain)

    store_ctx.verify_certificate()
```

I get
OpenSSL.crypto.X509StoreContextError: [20, 0, 'unable to get local issuer certificate'] as an error.
I am unable to figure out how to fix this